# ImportError: cannot import name 'errors'

Tags: python-3.x, sockjs, aiohttp, sockjs-tornado

Using sockjs with Tornado. On server run, this is the trace returned :

```
python server.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 10, in <module>
    from sockjs.tornado import SockJSRouter
  File "/Users/mohit/anaconda/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sockjs/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from sockjs.route import get_manager, add_endpoint
  File "/Users/mohit/anaconda/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sockjs/route.py", line 11, in <module>
    from sockjs.transports import handlers
  File "/Users/mohit/anaconda/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sockjs/transports/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .jsonp import JSONPolling
  File "/Users/mohit/anaconda/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sockjs/transports/jsonp.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .base import StreamingTransport
  File "/Users/mohit/anaconda/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sockjs/transports/base.py", line 2, in <module>
    from aiohttp import errors
ImportError: cannot import name 'errors'
```

Comment: Could you try fixing the version as `sockjs-tornado==1.0.3` in your requirements.txt file?

Comment: @zatta : I installed v1.0.3, same error.

Comment: @McGrady : I don't have asyncio installed.

Comment: Is there a chance you are using https://github.com/aio-libs/sockjs project? I think you have a collision as sockjs is hard copied in the directory, you will need to delete the directory or install aiohttp by `pip install aiohttp` as requirement is visible in `setup.py`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to upgrade python version to
Python 3.5+ and utilize PEP-492 aka async/await. If you are using Python 3.4 please replace await with yield from and async def with @coroutine e.g.:

`async def coro(...):
    ret = await f()`

should be replaced by:

`@asyncio.coroutine
def coro(...):
    ret = yield from f()`

from aiohttp documentaion:

Dependencies
**Python 3.4.2+**

`chardet`, `multidict`, `async_timeout`, `yarl`

Optionally you may install the cChardet and aiodns libraries (highly recommended for sake of speed).

`$ pip install cchardet`

`$ pip install aiodns`